# How can I dislodge ETH suck in contract during a Bitstamp -> Bitfinex transfer?

Tags: contract-invocation

Question: 
Can anyone help me?
TX Hash: 0x852be4473b53c8426962c25eb45dd19a7a35418e7b258108c5c57993a11184b6

Nutshell:
Asked Bitfinex for an ETH deposit address and received one, 0xD7f4864f0883E3521b5A888e57DAc133431b7160.

Asked Bitstamp to send the ~32 ETH to that address, they did, transaction "completed".

Turns-out the ETH was processed by a smart contract that was instructed to transfer the ETH to my deposit address but has not.

Bitstamp says that the transaction completed on their end.
Bitfinex won't respond to my customer support tickets.

Any direction would be *greatly* appreciated(!).

--jtcrew

Comment: There's nothing that can be done, just wait for Bitfinex customer support. If you check the ethers are still in that account https://etherscan.io/address/0xd7f4864f0883e3521b5a888e57dac133431b7160.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did they help you to solve the problem?